# How do I set an environmental variable for a GNOME session?

Tags: linux, unix, gnome, environment-variables

On my system, for apps that use SDL, I need to set an environmental variable:

```
export SDL_AUDIODRIVER=alsa
```

to get the sound to work properly. How do I set up my GNOME session so that this variable is present for all applications (so if I run an application through Nautilus, or use [DBGL](http://members.quicknet.nl/blankendaalr/dbgl/), the apps work properly)?

EDIT:

Configuration files I have set (and reset my machine after each) to no avail:

- `.xsession`
- `.xsessionrc`
- `.gnomerc`
- `.bash_profile`
- `.profile`<-- This works in the general case, but not when your distro is setting the variable elsewhere.
- `/etc/profile`

Comment: Are you sure this needs to be an environment variable? Seems like it might be some other kind of setting. Have you dug around in the system sound settings applet?

Comment: It does indeed. This is how SDL figures out what backend to use. I wish it just used a configuration file, but SDL is fairly consistent in its use of environmental variables to dictate behaviour.

Comment: have you seen this: http://modarchive.org/forums/index.php?topic=1879.0

Comment: Well yeah, it's a choice between recompiling SDL or setting an environmental variable. I think I'm making the right choice. :p This works (i.e., in a shell, it works) it's just the thorny issue of getting GNOME to propagate the variable for apps not started from a shell that's the issue. Thank you for your continuing help.

Comment: What distro is this in?! (I agree that the config for gdm is really hard to follow, so my first thought, "just look in /etc/gdm/ and read the scripts" is a lot of pain.) Here, .profile seems to work just fine. (debian/testing)

Comment: Also, are you sure that it's not really there (and SDL is ignoring it)? Can you echo it in an xterm? (set, then echo again?)

Comment: It's really not there. Run emacs in an xterm, it echos 'alsa' for M-x getenv. Run GTK+ version of emacs, it echos 'pulse'. I'm guessing the SUSE guys (OpenSUSE 11.1) are setting it somewhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be that the SDL_AUDIODRIVER variable is being unset somewhere. One strategy I use for problems with things related to startup scripts is to put in debug echo statements that is simple to enable/disable by creating/deleting a file. You could start by adding

```
debug_msg() {
        test -f $HOME/.debug && echo "$@" 1>&2
}

debug_msg "running ~/.bashrc ($0), SDL_AUDIODRIVER = '$SDL_AUDIODRIVER'"
```

to .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile and /etc/profile to see what value it has and if/where it is changing.

Comment: Mmm, that's my current thoughts as well. It's set to 'pulse', and that must be being set _somewhere_ by OpenSUSE. I'll do some detective work when I get home.

Comment: If anyone else is looking for an answer to the OP, this answer does not address it. It is useful debugging info but is not the answer,

Answer (score 12):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables talks about four places where we can set the environment variables:

> - `~/.pam_environment` - […] It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line. […] requires a re-login in order to initialize the variables. […]
> - `~/.profile` - This is probably the best file for placing environment variable assignments, since it gets executed automatically by the DisplayManager during the start-up process desktop session as well as by the login shell when one logs-in from the textual console.
> - `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` - If one of these file exist, bash executes it rather then "~/.profile" when it is started as a login shell. (Bash will prefer "~/.bash_profile" to "~/.bash_login"). However, these files won't influence a graphical session by default.
> - `~/.bashrc` - Because of the way Ubuntu currently sets up the various script files by default, this may be the easiest place to set variables in. The default configuration nearly guarantees that this file will be executed in each and every invocation of bash as well as while logging in to the graphical environment. However, performance-wise this may not be the best thing to do since it will cause values to be unnecessarily set many times.

http://userbase.kde.org/Session_Environment_Variables/en suggests this place for KDE:

> KDE will execute any script it finds in `$HOME/.kde/env` whose filename ends in `.sh`, and it will maintain all the environment variables set by them. It is important that any variable you want to set must be also exported.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#XIM suggests modifying `~/.gnomerc` or `~/.Xsession`.

Comment: ~/.pam_environment is not sourced. Now in 2020, despite documention and enabling user_readenv it still is not sourced.

Comment: Note that this does not apply to GNOME on Wayland; see [this answer to a different question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403196/39765).

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.gnomerc` file in your $HOME which is a shell script (*like `.bashrc`*) which sets all the variables you want.

Comment: This isn't working for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried opening gnome-terminal and confirmed it doesn't show up in env?

Comment: @Mike: it's in my .bashrc so it would show up, but it would be inaccurate. Emacs and `M-x getenv` confirms that it is not being overridden for GUI apps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the environment variable int **.profile** or **/etc/profile**?

That should work and should already exist. Unlike **.bashrc** which is per terminal session, these are initiated at login to your session.

Comment: Alas, no effect.

Comment: It depends on the login manager.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers do not apply to Gnome.  Some others may not work now.

See [Definition of user service environment](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/environment.d.html).

You can create (for yourself) a file like `~/.config/environment.d/*.conf` and define variables therein.

Example (for all users)

```
% more /etc/environment
#
# This file is parsed by pam_env module
#
# Syntax: simple "KEY=VAL" pairs on separate lines
#

EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano
```

From man `pam_env`:

```
PAM_ENV(8)                     Linux-PAM Manual                     PAM_ENV(8)

NAME
       pam_env - PAM module to set/unset environment variables
```

This will set environment at login, update needs logout login.

It will work with Gnome but is apparently more generally linked to systemd.

From Wikipedia:

> systemd is a software suite that provides an array of system
> components for Linux operating systems. The main aim is to unify
> service configuration and behavior across Linux distributions. Its
> primary component is a "system and service manager" — an init system
> used to bootstrap user space and manage user processes.